# Finding Recently Downloaded Files in Power Shell

Tags: powershell

I'm a blind user and I keep having to go find what's breaking a few people's computers and it's getting annoying.  They always click on "install this Active-X" or "download the free video player now" and I have to then dig through everything.
I whipped up a powershell script to search C:\ for files that have a write time of 5 minutes ago and less for testing purposes the Get-ChildItem part works.  Now I just want to get a list of file paths to make my life easier but I am missing something.
Here's what I have so far:

```
cd c:\
$fileizer = Get-ChildItem -Path . -exclude *.txt,*.log -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse| ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)}
echo $fileizer
```

Here are the results if I just do the Get-ChildItem part of it:

```
PS C:\Users\tryso> c:\bin\hours.ps1


    Directory: C:\bin


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         8/1/2017   2:44 PM            169 hours.ps1


PS C:\>
```

Obviously I am going to narrow down the path to something more specific than just C:\ like to get into C:\Windows\Temp and C:\Users\ and the likes, I'm just wondering how to parse everything to just give me a list of files and their path.
I'd also like to point out that 5 minutes old is dumb, yes I know.  I just did that to make it scream through my C:\ drive because you'd be amazed at how many files have a write time of .5 hours in C:\ LoL.
Ultimately I'd like to figure out how to find new files as opposed to recent write times if that's possible.
Sorry if my query is lame or a repeat, the only close examples I have found don't work for me for some reason and I'm pretty new at PS scripting - but it's getting pretty addicting and awesome LoL.

Thanks a million for any help!

Ryan

Comment: Your variable named `$Fileizer` contains many properties about each file. To get only the full path to the file, you can ask for the FullName property -
 e.g. changing it to be `echo $fileizer.FullName`.

Comment: For "New" files, try looking for CreationTime instead of LastWriteTime.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 1):

The Select-Object cmdlet can pull out the information you're looking for. Often you will want to know more than one piece of info on your results, so dot sourcing isn't going to be the most efficient.

Try something like this to see the full path, size and last modified timestamp:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -exclude .txt,.log -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)} | Select-Object FullName, Length, LastWriteTime
```